# Is possible making the spring joint's connected anchor movable during the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game with a rope swing hero and there are also flying cars and they are moving but my character's spring joint's connected anchor stays fixed at the first click point. It does not moving with car. When i was writing my code, i thought if i reference to connected anchor car's rigidbody's position with update function it should move with car but it did not. Whate should i do? Thanks from now.

And here is my code;

```
void StartGrapple()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, isGrappleable))
    {
        currentGrapplePosition = player.position;
        grapplePoint = hit.rigidbody.position;
        joint = player.gameObject.AddComponent<SpringJoint>();
        joint.autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;
        joint.connectedAnchor = grapplePoint += new Vector3(-4, 0, 0);

        float distanceFromPoint = Vector3.Distance(player.position, grapplePoint);

        joint.maxDistance = distanceFromPoint * 0.5f;
        joint.minDistance = distanceFromPoint * 0f;

        joint.spring = 60f;
        joint.damper = 40f;
        joint.massScale = 4.5f;

        lr.positionCount = 2;

        webShot.Play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only setting the [`Joint.connectedAnchor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Joint-connectedAnchor.html) is not enough!

> Position of the anchor **relative to the connected Rigidbody**.

And also have in mind that

> The position is given in **local coordinates of the connected rigidbody**, or in world coordinates if there is no connected rigidbody.

You want to set the [`Joint.connectedBody`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Joint-connectedBody.html)

> A reference to another rigidbody this joint connects to.
>
> **If not set then the joint connects the object to a fixed point in world space.**

```
joint.connectedBody = hit.rigidbody;
```

---

In addition to that

> ```
> joint.connectedAnchor = grapplePoint += new Vector3(-4, 0, 0);
> ```

This basically equals

```
grapplePoint = grapplePoint + new Vector3(-4, 0, 0);
joint.connectedAnchor = grapplePoint;
```

While in this case this might still be valid and return the same value it is probably not really what you want to do. In general you rather want to use

```
joint.connectedAnchor = grapplePoint + new Vector3(-4, 0, 0);
```

---

And then in general of using this at all personally I would rather simply use e.g.

```
joint.connectedAnchor = hit.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point);
```

which would instead simply be the point where you hit the other object.

Comment: Thanks but when i set `joint.connectedBody` my character does not swinging anymore, you are right it moving but not working like `joint.connectedAnchor`

Comment: the `joint.connectedAnchor` is just an offset between the `connectedBody` or the world and the attach point of the joint. The rest depends on your settings for the SpringJoint